# Are there any rules for a Snataka?

Tags: philosophy, ashram, living

Every ashram has its own rules and duties what are the duties of a Snataka?Just finding a job?

Answer (score 1):

He shall wear a lower and an upper garment

He shall carry a bamboo staff

He shall carry a pot filled with water

He shall wear a double sacrificial cord

He shall wear a turban, a skin as an upper garment, and shoes; carry an umbrella; maintain the sacred domestic fire; and offer the new-moon and full-moon sacrifices.

On the days of the moon’s change he should get the hair of his head, beard, and body shaved and his nails clipped.

He should ask for uncooked food from Brahmins, Ksatriyas, Vaisyas, and Rathakaras, or even for almsfood.

When he does so, he should stand in silence.

And with that food he should perform all the cooked oblations offered to gods and ancestors, as well as rites for securing prosperity.

By following this procedure, says Baudhayana, the supreme seers attain the highest abode of Prajapati, the supreme lord.

Bāudhāyana-dharma-sūtrá 1.5.1-13

Reference: Dharmasūtras - The Law Codes of Āpastamba, Gautama, Baudhāyana and Vasiṣṭha by Patrick Olivelle